# 'dxerr9.h': No such file or directory

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, directx

I am trying to compile a program I took off a cd from a book that uses directx to render 3d objects. when i press compile I get the following error

```
C1083: Cannot open include file: 'dxerr9.h': No such file or directory
```

I am using VC++ 2008 Express Edition and i am running off of Vista. I went to the following folder

[edit]

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (February 2010)\Include
```

I was able to find dxerr.h in the folder and the path is also being included in the VC++ Directories tab in the options window. dont know whats going on.

Comment: Regarding your latest edit: dxerr.h or dxerr9.h? If you were able to find dxerr.h but your code wants dxerr9.h, then I think I see the problem. ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems your program was written using older version of DirectX SDK. The 'dxerr9.h' is present at least in "Microsoft DirectX 9.0 SDK (December 2004)", but is absent at least in "Microsoft DirectX SDK (August 2009)".

Comment: I went to the includes folder and I was able to find a header file called Dxerr.h. could this be the samething. should I try that out instead

Comment: Yes, it was renamed to DxErr.h in one of the latest DirectX SDKs. The functions are also missing the 9 at the end now so you might have to change that too.

Answer (score 1):

I think VitalyVal was right. about the following:

> It seems your program was written using an older version of DirectX SDK. The 'dxerr9.h' is present at least in "Microsoft DirectX 9.0 SDK (December 2004)", but is absent at least in "Microsoft DirectX SDK (August 2009)".

I think the files now go by dxerr.h.  I removed the 9 to the header and lib files and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

That header was [precisely](https://forum.kodi.tv/showthread.php?tid=59306) duped in Aug2009 SDK, though that shouldn't surprise since it was already [two years](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/08/21/directx-sdks-of-a-certain-age/) older DX versions had been deprecated, thus allowing for just a single library for everything.

By the way, people might be interested to check [this post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/04/24/wheres-dxerr-lib/) for a kind of more updated version.

Comment: Can you please add some details that will help even if the link is down? Thank you!

Comment: Are you talking about the first two links (whose only purpose is "being references") or the last one? In this case (putting aside I don't see msdn going down) it seems more an "[incidental](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/12118/what-is-sufficient-context-for-an-incidental-additional-info-link)" information than anything.

Comment: If you think this is super user question I think you can flag the question.
If this was not intended as an answer but as a comment, you can add it as such. Thank you for your reply!

Comment: You haven't answered my question, anyway this was meant to be an answer and it was meant to be on stack (since is "development related"). The SU link just served to introduce the (very clever tbh) notion of "tangential/side" information which imo applies globally.

Comment: I don't want to reply. This answer is just an aggregation of links that leads to explanations of the original 10 years old accepted answer. I want to point out that you should add some information from the bunch of links you posted.  
Ganbatte!

Comment: Then we are talking about the first two links then, good. In this case yes, my answer is nothing else than the 7yo replies with links.